# Atomic transaction rsync on Windows client using cwrsync

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cygwin, rsync

Is there a way to do an atomic transaction rsync using cwrsync on Windows?

Meaning: I want the sync to fully complete or 'roll back' in the way that it's not being finalized, for example when a network connectivity problem occurs during a sync processs.

On the web, I found this

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/support/atomic-rsync

and was wondering whether there's similar solution for cwrsync on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--delay-updates         put all updated files into place at end
```

I don't know if it does what you want.

Either that, or duplicate the folder before rsync, rsync the dupe, then mv. It is still efficient wrt. to network bandwidth. edit: (maybe if you andd --inplace it becomes somewhat more efficient wrt. to local I/O).